# Cannot call $scope.form.$submitted in jasmine test: undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

Angularjs 1.3.0-beta.8

I am trying to test wether a form was submitted or not.

Here is the test

```
it ('should submit when I TELL IT TO DO SO!!!', function(){
  element.find('button').trigger('click'); // form button that calls submit funtion
  expect( element.isolateScope().validationFieldsForm.$valid ).toBe( true );
});
```

The above test works just fine. I have access to $valid as I should. However, when I run the same test again but revised like this...

```
it ('should submit when I TELL IT TO DO SO!!!', function(){
  element.find('button').trigger('click'); // form button that calls submit funtion
  expect( element.isolateScope().validationFieldsForm.$submitted ).toBe( true );
});
```

The test above will result in 'undefined'. In fact, if I even call $scope.myFormName.$submitted in the directive this does not work either, but $error, $valid, $invalid, $setValidity, etc... all work.

Angularjs says that $submitted should be available in the form control object.

> [angularjs form controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `$submitted` doesn't exist in the version you're using. See the [docs for 1.3.0-beta.8](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/docs/api/ng/type/form.FormController). This was added with [version 1.3.0-beta.18](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-beta18-spontaneous-combustion-2014-08-12)

Comment: You are correct! I am using two branches with different versions and have confused my options. Thank you for the reminder. My head hurts...